# Two particle operators

Tags: abstract-algebra, quantum-mechanics

General form of two particle operators is
$$\hat{B} = \sum\limits_{ij,kl} B_{ij,kl} \hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}^{\dagger}_j\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_l$$

and I am asked to compute the expected value of $\hat{B^2}$. Some algebra gives us:

$$\hat{B^2} = \sum\limits_{ij,kl, ab, cd} B_{ij,kl}B_{ab, cd} \hat{a}^{\dagger}_i\hat{a}^{\dagger}_j\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_l\hat{a}^{\dagger}_a\hat{a}^{\dagger}_b\hat{a}_c\hat{a}_d$$

When computing $\langle\{ n_k \} |\hat{B}^2 | \{n_k\} \rangle$ one gets nonzero terms only if the number of particles in every state doesn't change. Thus for every annihilation operator $\hat{a}$ we must have an creation operator $\hat{a}^\dagger$ acting on the same index.

The problem boils down to pairing the set $\{i,j,a,b\}$ with $\{k,l,c,d\}$ and splitting the sum over $N^8$ to subsets of that space, rearrange the operators to get the number operators $\hat{n}_i := \hat{a}_i^\dagger \hat{a}_i$ at which point such "subset" of $B^2$ acting on $|\{n_k\}\rangle$ will give us products of corresponding occupation numbers.

Yet, there are $4!$ pairs to be made, and we must also counts things like $i =j = a = k = l = c \neq b =d$ making it too hard to "brute force" by hand.

Since we are effectively looking at permutations there must exist a smart way of going on about this! Thus my question is:
how does one efficiently solve this? To make matters worse we have two cases, one for bosons where $B_{ij,kl} = B_{ji,kl} = B_{ji,lk} =B_{ij,lk}$ and the operators [commute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization#Operator_identities), second for fermions with $B_{ij,kl} = -B_{ji,kl} = B_{ji,lk} =-B_{ij,lk}$ and the operators [anticommute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization#Operator_identities_2).

Comment: I think this is exactly analogous to the application of Wick contractions to multiparticle states. Have you seen whether there are any useful shortcuts to get it right in Diagrammar (by t'Hooft and Veltmann)?

Comment: Never heard of these. Thank you for pointing me in a direction, I'll get to googling.